# In Xamarin.Forms, what unit-of-measure is intrinsically associated with the number

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In Xamarin.Forms, what unit-of-measure is intrinsically associated with the number? Example if I write `<Button WidthRequest="200" … />`

Then here what is 200?  Points or Pixels or something else?
Because in Android we are using Density Pixel(DP)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In summary, a Xamarin.Forms programmer targeting phones and tablets
>   can assume that all units of measurement are based on the following
>   criterion:
>
> 160 units to the inch, equivalent to 
>   64 units to the centimeter

More information can be found in the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/creating-mobile-apps-xamarin-forms/summaries/chapter05).